# Android ImageView contains two images instead of one

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, imageview

I have a ImageView with the following layout

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/view_row_circular_icon_with_text_icon"
  style="@style/ImageView"
  android:layout_width="52dp"
  android:layout_height="52dp"
  android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_broadband_router_white"/>
```

The `android:src` property is useful for previewing this component.

And I set the image I want do display with the following

```
ImageView mIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view_row_circular_icon_with_text_icon_bg);
mIcon.setImageDrawable(rowEntry.getIcon());
```

`rowEntry.getIcon()` returns a Drawable.

The end result is both the image from `android:src` property and the image set from `mIcon.setImageDrawable()` in the ImageView.

How can I programmatically override the image so that only the latter is shown?

Comment: you're using different resource id

Comment: your id is different in both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see that your setting image of a another view which

```
R.id.view_row_circular_icon_with_text_icon_bg
```

Check the proper id and set the image

Comment: Yeah, I was pretty dumb for not noticing that. Thanks.